# Android - prevent dialog from resizing when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android activity which I need to not resize when Keyboard opens.

In my activity I have an EditText, ExpandableListView and a horizontally oriented LinearLayout containing 2 buttons which are all inside a vertically oriented LinearLayout, the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUserNameFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@+string/searchUsersHint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5pt"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" 
        android:clickable="True"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="True"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ok" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and I set my activity to open as dialog the following way:

```
 <activity android:name=".SelectUsersDialog"
              android:label="@string/select_users" android:excludeFromRecents="True" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

I can't prevent my dialog from resizing when keyboard opens.
I tried adding windowSoftInputMode values to my activity in the manifest the following way:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but it didn't help.

 I tried also other combinations of windowSoftInputMode but non of them worked.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You got any solution for this problem??